# npm dependency management best practices

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm a relative newcomer to the node community. I recently got on board so that I could put together a build for a complex web application that's been under development for several years. The two key tools in my build are Grunt and Browserify, but the application uses jQuery, Backbone, d3 and a smattering of other libraries and plugins as well.

A problem that I've been running into is this: by default, when I install and save a package with npm, it sets up the package with a semver expression that captures all future releases of the package whenever you run `npm update`. Like [this article](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right/) explains well, that may seem like a good thing at first ("give me this package and all future upgrades"), but it exposes your own application to any non-backwards compatible updates the package maintainer makes... The article also provides some recommended best practices, but it was written almost 4 years ago to the day; I'm hoping there are other, newer ideas.

What sort of solutions do you use to resolve this issue? I can't keep wasting time updating my software every time a breaking change is made in a library I rely on. I want to update when I am good and ready, not whenever I run `npm update`.

Comment: so why can't you just set the specific (1) version for each library you need in your package.json? npm respects this.

Comment: That's totally a viable solution, but there are some drawbacks. For one thing it's kind of annoying to manually specify the package version. For another, it may not be the case that I only want a particular version-- maybe I want some upgrades, just not backwards-incompatible ones. `npm` does offer support for that with its `^` and `~` prefixes, too, which I should've read about before posting. What I've learned from this is that package maintainers can' be trusted with determining the backwards-compatibility of their work, so `^` is questionable in a production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to save the tree of dependencies containing the exact versions, so when you `npm install` it'll use those exact versions.

The `npm outdated` command will tell you what packages are outdated.

Instead of `npm update` which updates all your packages, update specific packages with `npm install <pkg>@<version> --save`